# Rewrite url to sub domain in NGINX

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, uri

I currently have a image being outputted by server side PHP at a url like this:

**domain.com/m/image.jpg**

I'd like to have this image viewable at the url:

**i.domain.com/image.jpg**

Is this possible in the nginx conf?

Note: I currently have my "i" subdomain remapped to a /images/ folder.
Also I'm currently serving static images like the following:

```
http://i.domain.com/simage.jpg (thumb)
http://i.domain.com/image.jpg (medium)
http://i.domain.com/oimage.jpg (full quality)
```

Here's my domain.conf file: http://pastebin.com/BBWUJFxu

Also within nginx.conf I have this for the subdomain currently:

```
    #setup subdomain i.domain.com
server {
    server_name i.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/i.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/i.domain.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/domain.com/html/images;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {            
        #change this to a 404 img file .jpg
        try_files $uri $uri/ /notfound.jpg;

        rewrite  "/s([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /small/$1 break;
        rewrite  "/o([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /orig/$1 break;
        rewrite  "/([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /medium/$1 break;

    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com permanent;
    }

}
```

The third rewrite is the one I'm looking to replace with my non static served image file, any idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2:**

Ok, so the actual files are in `/images/size/image.jpg` and not actually `/m/`, `/m/` is just a psuedo directory.

Given that, I think it should be as simple as:

```
server {
    server_name i.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/i.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/i.domain.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/domain.com/html/images;

    location / {            
        rewrite  /s([A-Za-z0-9.]+)? /small/$1 break;
        rewrite  /o([A-Za-z0-9.]+)? /orig/$1 break;
        rewrite  /([A-Za-z0-9.]+)? /medium/$1 break;

        #change this to a 404 img file .jpg
        try_files $uri $uri/ /notfound.jpg;
    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com permanent;
    }

}
```

But not 100% sure on it. Give that a shot and see. I moved the try below, as it was trying the files, which did not exist, first and then erroring out.

---

**UPDATE**

<del>Since you are trying to just pass it through to a script, we need to capture that and pass it through to the script. I changed the root, since you are doing a "psuedo" images directory and we will need access to the image processing script.</del>

Ok, since there is no PHP script in the middle (mis-read on my part) then the below should do what you want it to.

```
#setup subdomain i.domain.com
server {
    server_name i.domain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/i.domain.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/i.domain.com.error.log;

    root /var/www/domain.com/html;

    location ~* \.jpg {  # add more extensions if you need to
        #change this to a 404 img file .jpg
        try_files $uri $uri/ /m/$uri /m/notfound.jpg;

        #get the main part working first
        #rewrite  "/s([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /small/$1 break;
        #rewrite  "/o([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /orig/$1 break;
        #rewrite  "/([A-Za-z0-9.]+)?" /medium/$1 break;

    }

    location = / {
        rewrite ^ http://domain.com permanent;
    }

}
```

If that works, I am not sure how to go about doing the rewrites for the small / orig / medium (as I am not sure about the logic needed), but hopefully you can get it working.

---

In your domain conf, you just need to add a location for `/m`

```
location /m {
    rewrite ^/m/(.*)$ http://i.domain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Should do it, pending any minor mistakes.

Comment: @eeek Not sure what you did wrong, I just tried it on my setup and it worked as expected. If the `http://i.domain.com/image.jpg` does not exist, then it will 404 error. So check that, also make sure you are reloading or restarting nginx after the change, also make sure you changed the `domain.com`

Comment: Well it doesnt exist anywhere other than domain.com/m/image.jpg  (which is a php script serving an image), how do i get that to be viewable at i.domain.com/image.jpg?

Comment: @eeek updated the answer. I would check if the image exists in your php script, if not serve the notfound.jpg image.

Comment: It looks like it's looking for the php script on the "i" subdomain? If so it doesnt exist there, its on the main domain only.

Comment: It should access it, you just might have to add the php / fastcgi location from the original server config to this one for it to work. I updated the server config, that *should* work pending any errors, but basically it allows pass-thru to the images_script using the sub-domain.

Comment: what's confusing me is you've invented this 'images_script\.php' it doesnt exist, the exactly php url is domain.com/m/image.jpg that's it, no php etc :S

Comment: Tried what you said but replaced the .php script with m/ and resulted in 500 error on all images.

Comment: Well we are on different pages then. I gathered you are using a php script to serve the images from this: `I currently have a image being outputted by server side PHP at a url like this:` If that is incorrect let me know the work process.  IE, what happens with you goto `/m/image.jpg` is there an actual file at `html/m/image.jpg` or is there a php script serving that file? Sorry, I just re-read the question and saw that first part which led me to believe that there is a php script in the middle serving the images.

Comment: image.jpg is located in html/images/medium/image.jpg, the i.domain.com subdomain is mapped to html/images/

Comment: currently, i then have images/medium/image.jpg rewriting to i.domain.com/image.jpg. along with the thumbnail version at i.domain.com/simage.jpg and full resolution i.domain.com/oimage.jpg (note the thumb and full resolution, i would like those to remain STATIC)

Comment: @eeek I see, sorry for wasting your time. I think the updated answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: 500 error, someone told me just now you cant rewrite across server blocks, that might be messing it up perhaps

Comment: What is the error associated with the 500? It should say in the logs. And I am not sure about the rewrite across server blocks, we are basically telling it to goto a different server, so I do not see why this would not work. If I get a chance I will see if I cannot setup a test on my server.

Comment: @eeek I also removed the quotes from the rewrite, maybe they were causing an issue, not sure. It is worth a shot though.

Comment: Whats the error inside the nginx logs? That would help if there is a useful error there.

Comment: There's alot but i think this is the one "20029 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/m/notfound.jpg", c"

Comment: Can you update your post with your current nginx conf file for me?

Comment: Here http://pastebin.com/wiFUiTk7 it's now working at i.domain.com/m/image.jpg with that proxy line, but now id like to move that link to i.domain.com/image.jpg (without the m). Any idea? Once that's done it'd be perfect